# MATLAB How can I input all the data using xlswrite for each loop?

Tags: excel, matlab, loops

For each loop I extract 4 data. (e.g. mean1, mean2, var1, var2)

So I want to put the data into excel file using xlswrite.

Like :

```
xlswrite('Table.xlsx', mean(accuracy1), 1, 'A1')
xlswrite('Table.xlsx', mean(accuracy2), 1, 'A2')
xlswrite('Table.xlsx', var(accuracy1), 1, 'I1')
xlswrite('Table.xlsx', var(accuracy2), 1, 'I2')
```

As you can see, for the first loop I want to input means in the A1 and A2.
And variances in the I1 and I2.

But for second loop I want to input new means in the B1 and B2.
Also variances in the J1 and J2.

For third loop means are in C1 and C2 and variances in K1 and K2.

How can I modify the code?

Do I have to change the letter (A,B,C and I,J,K) for each loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the results to a matrix and then write the data at once. Therefore you can address a range like `A1:C2` rather than a single cell. I used two calls to `xlswrite` here to not confuse the two 'parts'. With your specification of column `I` being the start of the second 'part', there are maximum 8 possible loops.

```
M1 = zeros(2,8);                                    % preallocate
M2 = zeros(2,8);                                    % preallocate

for i = 1:8
    accuracy1 = rand(100,1);                        % generate random data 
    accuracy2 = rand(100,1);                        % generate random data
    M1(:,i) = [mean(accuracy1);mean(accuracy2)];    % add mean
    M2(:,i) = [var(accuracy1);var(accuracy2)];      % add variance
end

xlswrite('Table.xlsx', M1, 1, 'A1:H2')              % write first part
xlswrite('Table.xlsx', M2, 1, 'I1:P2')              % write second part
```